# Math induction problem with large numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction, divisibility, decimal-expansion

I am trying to figure out how to prove $17^{200} - 1$ is a multiple of $10$. I am talking simple algebra stuff once everything is set in place.

I have to use mathematical induction.

I figure I need to split $17^{200}$ into something like $(17^{40})^5 - 1$ and have it as $n = 17^{40}$ and $n^5 - 1$.

I just don't know if that's a good way to start.

Comment: You are absolutely required to use induction to solve for one specific case?

Comment: i have to use induction. Its a problem in the mathematical induction chapter. I cant just punch it in a calculator and solve it

Comment: Prove in general that $17^{4n}-1$ is divisible by $10$. Or prove that $n(n^4-1)$ is always divisible by $5$, and thus when $n$ is not divisible by $5$, $n^4-1$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Where is 17 ^ 4n coming from?

Comment: What i tried to do is what i said about and by n=k, then k becomes (k+1) i change 17 ^ 200 to 17^(20)^(10) and n = 17^20  so n^10 = 1. Then  (k+1)^10 - 1 and then i foiled it out so it gives me  k^10 + ..... + 10(k^2 +2k)^3 which is a multiple of 10.  is that right?

Comment: @alexx I tried to indicate where the exponent choice of $4n$ in $17^{4n}$ comes up in an answer (although I have not used induction to flesh out the sort of proof your course is likely after).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it seems a bit strange to use induction to solve for particular case ($17^{200} - 1$), and it seems from your question that you want to see this solved via an inductive proof, let's use induction to solve a somewhat more general problem, and recover this particular example as a special case.

So, let's make the conjecture that 
$$4 \mid n \implies 10 \mid (17^n - 1).$$
This means we want to show 10 divides $17^{4k} - 1$ for all integers $k$.  Now, the base case is $k = 1$ and we have
$$ 17^{4k} - 1 = 17^4 - 1 = 83520 = 10 * 8352.$$
Indeed, the hypothesis holds in the base case.

Now, assume the statement is true for some integer $m$.  We then have
\begin{align*}
 &&17^{4m} - 1 &= 10 \cdot a &\text{for some } a \in \mathbb{Z} \\
 \implies && 17^4 (17^{4m} - 1) &= 10 \cdot a \\
 \implies && 17^{4m+1} - 83521 &= 10 \cdot a \\
 \implies && 17^{4m+1} - 1 &= 10\cdot a + 83520 \\
 \implies && 17^{4m+1} - 1 &= 10\cdot (a + 8352) 
\end{align*}
Thus, 10 divides $17^{4m+1}$ if it divides $17^{4m}$; hence, we have shown that 10 divides $17^{4k}$ for every integer $k$.

Since 200 is a multiple of 4, the problem at hand is then solved as a special case of this theorem.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I just didnt know if this way was the right approach but your example is the same as I was shown. Thank you for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: @alexx No problem.  I hope a detailed example is helpful.  Although, as you can see from the other answer, there are faster ways to prove this without using induction.

Comment: You can simplify the argument by noting that $17^2= 289 = 10a-1$ implies $17^4= 10b+1$.

Comment: Surely you mean $4m+4$ or $4(m+1)$ in your exponents.

Comment: Not that it matters to recover the special case in the actual question, but you only proved one direction of your $\iff$.

Comment: It's totally fine to use induction to solve "one specific case." We're trying to prove things that can actually be applicable at some point. If you prove 1+...+n = n(n+1)/2 by induction are you allowed to use this fact when asked to find 1+...+2015 or do you need to find some other way that's not induction now that it's a specific case?

Answer (score 8):

Consider a number with a $7$ in its units place. As we take powers of it, the units digit proceeds:

$$7, 9, 3, 1, 7, 9, 3, 1, \ldots$$

Notice that when raised to a power that is a multiple of $4$, such a number ends up with a $1$ in its units place. Since $17$ has a $7$ in its units place, and since $200$ is a multiple of $4$, we reason that the number $17^{200}$ must have a $1$ in its units place. Thus, $17^{200} - 1$ has a $0$ in its units place, i.e., is a multiple of $10$ as desired. **QED**.

Comment: A good proof (or demonstration, if one wants to be picky), but not an inductive one as the question required. However I do think this is good motivation for the step that is missing in several of the other answers, which is why one should try to prove $10 \vert (17^{4n} - 1)$ in the first place.

Comment: By the way, for those that aren't aware, the general method for proving divisibility in this way is called modular arithmetic. This solution considered the given number in modulo 10.

Comment: @DavidZ Right: The OP indicated a lack of surety around "a good way to start." And so I hope this *demonstration* responds in that direction! Perhaps my **QED** is a bit heavy-handed; to turn this from a demonstration into a formal proof (in a course broaching induction) involves justification around where I simply wrote, "notice that..." One can use induction to do precisely this, which is what the OP's selected answer chose to do with its "conjecture."

Answer (score 6):

$17^{200} - 1$ is clearly even and so it remains to prove that it is a multiple of $5$.

Now, $17^{200}= (15+2)^{200}=15a+2^{200}$. So it suffices to prove that $2^{200}-1$ is a multiple of $5$.

Indeed, $2^{200}=(2^{4})^{50}=16^{50}=(5b+1)^{50}=5c+1$.

Comment: Induction is in the binomial theorem, which is used twice.

Comment: this might be a stupid question but what does the a a, b and c stand for? Constants? I was thought with k and k+1 sorry for asking

Comment: $a,b,c$ are some integers whose exact values are immaterial to the argument.

Answer (score 6):

We need to prove that for all $n$,  $17^{4n} -1$ is divisible by 10.

Consider when n=1:

$17^{4} - 1 = (17^{2} - 1)(17^{2} +1)=(288)(290)$

this is obviously divisible by 10.

Assume for some integer k that $17^{4k} -1$ is divisible by 10.

Then $17^{4(k+1)} -1 =17^{4k+4} -1=(17^{4})(17^{4k}) -1 
= (17^{4k} -1) + (17^{4} -1)(17^{4k}) = (17^{4k} -1) + (288)(290)(17^{4k}) $

And both parts of the last sum are divisible by 10 as required.

Comment: Or simply, $17^{4k}-1=(17^4-1)(\cdots)$ from $x^k-1=(x-1)(x^{k-1}+\cdots+x+1)$.

Comment: But that wouldn't require induction. The question specifically asked for induction.

Comment: It does require induction to prove that $x^k-1=(x-1)(x^{k-1}+\cdots+x+1)$.

Comment: I assume they meant to prove the proposition directly with induction, rather than proving another theorem that would simplify the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another proof that $k(k^4-1)$ is divisible by $10$, using some "fun" observations ;)

The base case is $2(2^4-1) = 30$, which is easily seen to be $3\cdot10$
Assume $k^5-k = 10 a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$(k+1)^5-(k+1)$$
$$=\left(k^5+5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k+1\right)-(k+1)$$
$$=k^5+5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k-k$$
$$=(k^5-k)+5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k$$
$$10a+5(k^4+2k^3+2k^2+k)$$
Since an odd times and odd is odd and an even times and even is even, so $k^4+k$ is either $(2k+1)+(2r+1) = 2(r+k+1)$ or $2n+2r=2(n+r)$ and thus must be even, so we rewrite the above as
$$10a+5(2(k^3+k^2+p)) = 10(a+k^3+k^2+p)$$
Examining $17^{200}-1$, we realize that $17^{200}-1$ must be divisible by $10$ if $17^{50}$ is not. $17^{50}$ *has* no factors of $10$ though (as it is prime), so  $17^{200}-1$ must be divisible by $10$.